# graphql query cost analysis on client side

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am consuming a graphql API. The API sends the requestedCost and the actualCost in the response. I want to calculate the requestedCost at the client side to rate limit my requests.

I have the rules for calculating the cost. For example, an object costs 1 point, fields cost zero points, connections cost 2 points etc.

I am experimenting with the AST using the graphql parse and visit functions and it seems to work but I think there may be a better way.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Have you seen this library named [`graphql-query-complexity`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-query-complexity)? You could follow the idea described in the library and use estimators to assign each node a value. Then traverse the AST and sum the values to get the full complexity of the query.